# Failed to activate systemd service

Tags: systemd, fedora, conky

I have a personal Conky script (at `~/.conky/conky-launch.sh`) that I'd like to execute every time I boot up my OS (which is Fedora Workstation 39). So, I created a `systemd` service file named `personal-conky.service` as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Opens up my personal conky setup on boot

[Service]
User=arch
ExecStart=/home/arch/.conky/conky-launch.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next, I enabled the service by doing:

```bash
$ sudo systemctl enable personal-conky.service
```

When I rebooted however I found that the script has not executed. When I did:

```bash
$ systemctl status personal-conky.service
```

I got the following error:

```
× personal-conky.service - Opens up my personal conky setup on boot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/personal-conky.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-01-31 20:12:57 IST; 4s ago
   Duration: 3ms
    Process: 5602 ExecStart=/home/arch/.conky/conky-launch.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 5602 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms

Jan 31 20:12:57 fedora systemd[1]: Started personal-conky.service - Opens up my personal conky setup on boot.
Jan 31 20:12:57 fedora (aunch.sh)[5602]: personal-conky.service: Failed to locate executable /home/arch/.conky/conky-launch.sh: Permission denied
Jan 31 20:12:57 fedora (aunch.sh)[5602]: personal-conky.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/arch/.conky/conky-launch.sh: Permission denied
Jan 31 20:12:57 fedora systemd[1]: personal-conky.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 31 20:12:57 fedora systemd[1]: personal-conky.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Why is this happening, and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: This question could point you in the right direction: https://superuser.com/questions/1025091/start-a-systemd-user-service-at-boot

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the shell in the Exec line:
`ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/arch/.conky/conky-launch.sh`

I believe you may not need the interpreter (bash) if you change the mode to `+x`, but I'm not certain.  Also, change the path to bash if needed.

### Source

[How to create a systemd service in Linux](https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/)